Is the map $M\mapsto P$ smooth, where $P$ satisfies $PMP^{-1} = M^T$?
From this post (and other similar ones) we know, in particular, that $$ \forall M\in{\rm GL}(n,\Bbb R),\ \exists P\in{\rm GL}(n,\Bbb R)\ \text{s.t. } PMP^{-1} = M^T\ . \tag{$*$} $$
My question is about the smoothness of the map $F:{\rm GL}(n,\Bbb R)\to{\rm GL}(n,\Bbb R)$ given by $M\mapsto P$, where $P$ satisfies $(*)$ above. Is $F$ smooth as a map between Lie groups?
From the answers to the above linked post, one possible way to construct $P$ (given an $M$) is using the Jordan Canonical Form. Then I suspect that the entries of $P$ may depend polynomially (or in general smoothly) on the entries of the corresponding matrix $M$. But I can't seem to find a reference for this or convince myself "more" rigorously that this is true. So, Is this true? TIA.

Do you mean $F(M) = P$, where $PMP^{-1} = M^T$?

@MatthewLeingang : oh yes! You're right. Very sorry. Can't believe I confused those. I've edited my post.

Is $P$ unique? I should know that, but I don't. If not, this isn't a function. But you might be able to use the implicit function theorem to show that, in the neighborhood of some $(M_0,P_0)$, $P$ depends smoothly on $M$.

@MatthewLeingang Certainly not unique, see $n=1$. Moreover, if $P$ is a solution, then $\lambda P$ is another for all $\lambda\ne0$.

@SassatelliGiulio right you are!

Moreover, well, you are intersecting a vector subspace with $GL(n,\Bbb R)$, so in general we expect the solution set for $P_M$ to be a (non-empty) open subset of $\ker(X\mapsto XM-M^TX)$.

As others have said, your $F$ is not well-defined. Basically you are considering $E={(M,P)\mid PMP^{-1}=M^T}$ and asking if the projection $\pi(M,P)=M$ has a smooth section. (Note the fiber $\pi^{-1}(M)$ is always a coset of ${\rm Stab}(M)$ so it varies with $M$.)

Thank you all for your comments. I think these comments answer my questions!
